# Pairwise distances of all rows in n dimensional matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a `n` dimensional matrix `A` i.e `nXn...Xn` matrix and I would like to calculate the sum of all pairwise distances of the rows in the matrix. The distance can be euclidean or any other defined distances.

I tried the example given in `scipy` using `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`, however it does not work on n dimensional matrices (requiring a `mXn` matrix as stated in the documentation).

For a 2d matrix,

```
A = [ a b c , 
      d e f ,
      g h i ]
```

the euclidean distance between all possible pair of observations is defined as

```
Sum = sqrt( (a-d)^2 + (b-e)^2 + (c-f)^2 ) ) +  sqrt( (a-g)^2 + (b-h)^2 + (c-i)^2 ) ) + sqrt( (g-d)^2 + (h-e)^2 + (i-f)^2 ) )
```

I would like to extend the above concept of distance of a 2d matrix (taking every pairwise row and calculating distance between them).

```
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

   [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

   [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]])
```

What would be the quickest way to calculate the same using vectorization ?

Comment: Add sample cases?

Comment: Is an `n` dimensional matrix not simply a `1 x n` matrix in disguise?

Comment: Do you mean flatten my existing array to a `1 X n` matrix ? How would the pairwise work in that case.

Comment: When you said "I have a `n` dimensional matrix" I assumed you meant it was `1 x n`. If it isn't, what's the `m`?

Comment: That looks like 2D and should be solvable by pdist/cdist. Could you show how pdist didn't work for you?

Comment: Hi @Divakar, Apologies as I was editing the question. I would like to extend the concept to a 3d matrix. Calculating `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist` on the last array yields as `ValueError` mentioning that a 2D array is required.

Comment: Not exactly clear from the sample. Add a working loopy solution or pseudo one maybe?

Comment: Or can you simply reshape the array to 2D : `a.reshape(-1,a.shape[-1])`, use `pdist`, get the distance output and reshape back to `3D` or `2D` with `squareform`?